# Is there any Operations Research group in Clubhouse?

Tags: optimization

Since the introduction of the Clubhouse app, there are several groups on different topics and people can talk about specific topics in different fields. Is there any group related to "Operations Research" in Clubhouse?
I would be thankful if well-known researchers and scholars in the forum can make a group In CH.

Comment: The question title should be edited to say "Operations Research group", which I just did. Other than that, this seems to be a legitimate question to me. I know some very technical people have done interviews relating to Machine Learning and similar in Clubhouse, so the question doesn't seem off the wall. Disclaimer: I don't have the app myself, and have never listened to any Clubhouse event.

Comment: Clubhouse is only available for iPhone and promotes a very exclusive (in contrast to inclusive) user base/community. IMO, this is not the way to go. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Would definitely be interested in joining a group like this in case someone is starting one. Preferably a group of OR practitioners rather than a group of academics.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about operations research but there is a club called stackexchange in clubhouse. Do join and you can start a topic of your own.

https://www.clubhouse.com/join/stackexchange/FrzrVmPK